# Atmospheric correction for Landsat 8 data in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

What is the code for this? Already mosaic'ed my image

Answer (score 3):

GEE doesn't have a specific algorithm to atmospherically correct scenes, just `Cloud Score` in Landsat case. Instead to trying to correct images, use Surface Reflectance products:

> **USGS Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 1**
>
> This dataset is the atmospherically corrected surface reflectance from
>   the Landsat 8 OLI/TIRS sensors. These images contain 5 visible and
>   near-infrared (VNIR) bands and 2 short-wave infrared (SWIR) bands
>   processed to orthorectified surface reflectance, and two thermal
>   infrared (TIR) bands processed to orthorectified brightness
>   temperature
>
> These data have been atmospherically corrected using LaSRC and
>   includes a cloud, shadow, water and snow mask produced using CFMASK,
>   as well as a per-pixel saturation mask.
>
> Strips of collected data are packaged into overlapping "scenes"
>   covering approximately 170km x 183km using a standardized reference
>   grid.

Usage:

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T2_SR");
```